# Wordpress- broken links in sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fix the left sidebar on this page http://spanishsilvervillages.com/village-homes/ but found nothing that can fix this issue. In that sidebar I have broken links which are going to 404 not found page. please help me with editing that sidebar links. Thank you!

Comment: What's the html for the links you have in the widget?

Comment: While adding the menu links, you have made a mistake. I see your web url us `http://spanishsilvervillages.com/` while your links URL go like this `http://spanishsilvervillage.p-w-d.co.uk/`

Comment: where do i find this widget..?

Comment: Hi, @Viswalinga, now how to fix that links as I am newbie wordpress user.

Comment: In your Wordpress admin, Go to Appearance > Menus. Check the menu links in the page.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS I checked all the menus but none of the page have links added to it. please tell where do i check for those links here is the screen shot of my screen. http://s28.postimg.org/webulqlwd/Screenshot_from_2014_04_09_20_08_14.png

Comment: From the dropdown **Select a menu to edit**, check the other menus. When you change that dropdown, menu items associated with that will be replaced at the bottom. Check in that.

Comment: You can refer here, http://s30.postimg.org/6836qph81/bliss.jpg

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS, i did exactly as you said and also I gone through every menus listed in that drop down, clicking on that menus didnot made any changes to that link box you mentioned in your 4th point...

Answer (score 0):

Check the links in your widgets box.

Your dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets -> menu sidebar widget (and/or any other widgets you have there)

Expand that widget and check if the links there are correct.

Comment: Click on the down arrow beside the widget name?

Comment: there is no sidebar widget... i have there only these: search, recent posts, recent comments, archieves, categories and meta.

Answer (score 0):

Login inside your Wordpress admininistration area and Go to menu `Appearance > Menus`.

Then check the every menu link and save changes. Keep in mind, that if you build big (+200 total items) menu, then you *may* need to change a so called `suhosin` variables in your `php.ini` file, in order changes to be saved, as such:

`suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000`